# Add inputfield based on selected value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add input fields based on the selected values from Dropdown list.
I want to append the input fields on a `<div>`. I really tried a lot but I cant find the mistakes. Maybe someone in this community see's it already...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();
    
    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);
    
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
        nextTab($active);

    });
    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        prevTab($active);

    });
    
   // $(document).on('ready', function() {
   // $("#input-4").fileinput({showCaption: false});
//});
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}


//according menu

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
    $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
 
 //Set The Accordion Content Width
 var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
 $('.accordion-content').css({});
 
 //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
 $('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
 $('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
 
 // The Accordion Effect
 $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
  if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
   $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
   $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
   $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
  }
  
  else {
   $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
   $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
  }
 });
 
 return false;
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Wizard.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Wizard.js"></script>
        <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wizard.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section>
                    <div class="wizard">
                        <div class="wizard-inner">
                            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                                    <a href="#persInfo" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="persInfo" role="tab" title="Person">
                                        <span class="round-tab">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                                    <a href="#boxInfo" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="boxInfo" role="tab" title="Box">
                                        <span class="round-tab">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                                    <a href="#compInfo" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="compInfo" role="tab" title="Competition">
                                        <span class="round-tab">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                                    <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                                        <span class="round-tab">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="persInfo">
                                    <div class="persInfo">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Competition Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compName" placeholder="Competition Name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Registration Code for athletes</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Registration Code for athletes">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">


                                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Competition Date</label>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 wdth">

                                                        <select name="visa_status" id="visa_status" class="dropselectsec1">
                                                            <option value="">Day</option>
                                                            <option value="2">1</option>
                                                            <option value="1">2</option>
                                                            <option value="4">3</option>
                                                            <option value="5">4</option>
                                                            <option value="6">5</option>
                                                            <option value="3">6</option>
                                                            <option value="7">7</option>
                                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                                            <option value="9">9</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 wdth">

                                                        <select name="visa_status" id="visa_status" class="dropselectsec1">
                                                            <option value="">Month</option>
                                                            <option value="2">Jan</option>
                                                            <option value="1">Feb</option>
                                                            <option value="4">Mar</option>
                                                            <option value="5">Apr</option>
                                                            <option value="6">May</option>
                                                            <option value="3">June</option>
                                                            <option value="7">July</option>
                                                            <option value="8">Aug</option>
                                                            <option value="9">Sept</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 wdth">

                                                        <select name="visa_status" id="visa_status" class="dropselectsec1">
                                                            <option value="">Year</option>
                                                            <option value="2">1990</option>
                                                            <option value="1">1991</option>
                                                            <option value="4">1992</option>
                                                            <option value="5">1993</option>
                                                            <option value="6">1994</option>
                                                            <option value="3">1995</option>
                                                            <option value="7">1996</option>
                                                            <option value="8">1997</option>
                                                            <option value="9">1998</option>
                                                        </select>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Next</button></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="boxInfo">
                                    <div class="boxInfo">






                                        <script>
                                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                                $('select#selectDiv').change(function () {
                                                    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();

                                                    if (sel_value == 0) {
                                                        $("#test1").empty(); // Resetting Form

                                                    } else {
                                                        $("#test1").empty(); //Resetting Form
                                                        create(sel_value);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                                function create(sel_value) {
                                                    for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++) {
                                                        $("#test1").append($("<label/>").text(i + ". Division Name"), $("<input/>", {
                                                            class: 'form-control',
                                                            type: 'text',
                                                            name: 'name_' + i
                                                        }), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
                                                            type: 'text',
                                                            value: sel_value,
                                                            name: 'NumbDiv_' + i
                                                        }), $("<br/>"), $("<br/>"));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                        </script>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleSelect1">Number of Divisions</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="selectDiv" name="select" >
                                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6" id="test1">

                                        </div>






                                       
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Street</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Street">
                                        </div>



                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Back</button></li>
                                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Next</button></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>



                                <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="compInfo">
                                    <div class="compInfo">


                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Competition Name</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Competition Name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Competition Logo</label>
                                                <input id="input-4" name="input4[]" type="file" class="file-loading">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Street</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Street">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">City</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="City">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Postal Code</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Postal Code">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Country</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Country">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                     

                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Back</button></li>
                                        <!--<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>-->
                                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Next</button></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                                    <div class="step44">
                                        <h5>Completed</h5>

                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Back</button></li>
                                            <!--<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>-->
                                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Finish</button></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wizard.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you are missing a closing ')' for your append.

Comment: thx for that advice changed it but unfortunatelly it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element with id `test1`, there is a `test` though.

Also your append statement closes early, so you have a series of comma separated statement .

So

```
$("#test1").append($("<label/>").text(i + ". Division Name"))
                                        //move this bracket ^
...
}), $("<br/>"), $("<br/>");
        //and put it here ^
```

.

```
$("#test").append($("<label/>").text(i + ". Division Name"), $("<input/>", {
    class: 'form-control',
    type: 'text',
    name: 'name_' + i
}), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
    type: 'text',
    value: sel_value,
    name: 'NumbDiv_' + i
}), $("<br/>"), $("<br/>"));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select#selectDiv').change(function () {
        var sel_value = $(this).val();

        if (sel_value == 0) {
            $("#test").empty(); // Resetting Form
        }
        else {
            $("#test").empty(); //Resetting Form
            create(sel_value);
        }
    });
function create(sel_value) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++) {
        $("#test").append($("<label/>").text(i + ". Division Name"), $("<input/>", {
            class: 'form-control',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'name_' + i
        }), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
            type: 'text',
            value: sel_value,
            name: 'NumbDiv_' + i
        }), $("<br/>"), $("<br/>"));
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Number of Divisions</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectDiv" name="select" >
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help. The code you provided is correct. But as soon as I copy it on my bootrap code it doesnt work anymore :( 
Ive updated my whole code (if u run the code on the second tab house called box  i want to create input files based on selection

Comment: Hey thanks for the edit, but I already changed it on my code before. It still doesn't work. It seem it can get the values from the droptdown. I just updated my whole code if u want to take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake... I had to insert the ID before option selected 
 var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();

correct : var sel_value = $('#selectDiv option:selected').val();